# Masonry layout not triggered until window is again resized

Tags: html, css, layout, jquery-masonry, masonry

I start learning masonry short time ago. I want to use Masonry for the layout of my website, everything works fine, but there is an issue.

I did a code for window resize. when Someone resize the window, masonry layout change key to page width. I did not do it with Masonry so I did it with this code But when I run this code, something went wrong and Masonry layout change next windows resize. I dont know where problem is it.

Here is jsfiddle demo : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rgt6L4aw/)**

```
<script>
var doit;
window.onresize = function myFunction() {
clearTimeout(doit);
doit = setTimeout(function() {
    resizedw();
}, 1001);}


function resizedw(){
var w = window;
var d = document;
var e = d.documentElement;
var g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var originalwidth = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth; // sayfa boyutu
var orpagewidth = parseInt(originalwidth/200);

    var csswidth = $('#section_bg').css('width'); //returns 20px
var parsedcsswidth = parseInt(csswidth); //returns 20 div boyutu
var orcsswidth = parseInt(parsedcsswidth/200);

if (parsedcsswidth != originalwidth ){
if (parsedcsswidth > originalwidth ){ 
    $(".section_bg").animate({width:orpagewidth*200}, 500);}

if (parsedcsswidth < originalwidth ){ 
    $(".section_bg").animate({width:orpagewidth*200}, 500);}
}
}  
</script>
```

Comment: the fiddlelink is not set

Comment: I set fiddlelink now.

Comment: @BerkAltun You have it set to only do it when it resizes. Not when the page loads...... I'm not even sure what you have done to this... I have used Masonry before and have never used this much code.

Comment: I want to bring layout middle of page. When page is resize, script bring page width and change layout width.

Comment: @BerkAltun I have no idea what you mean, be clearer with what you want. You don't need to work out the width of the page. Use Percentage, here is a stupidly clean version of what you was trying to do [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0dynzgf/).

Comment: @Ruddy I want to make centered it. Margin left is equal to Margin right for this reason I try this... Also see it: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/centered.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the 1200px width and added container id to the element containing the blogposts to use  as masonry selector. Check the fiddle bellow, replaced all JS with the simple masonry code(it does the resize calculations for you)

```
$('#container').masonry({
   columnWidth: 190,
   gutter: 10,
   isAnimated: true,
   itemSelector: '.blogpost',
   isFitWidth: true
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgt6L4aw/5/)

EDIT: If you want the blogposts to be centered you can set isFitWidth to true, updated the fiddle to show this